# addEventListener not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning addEventListener,I was testing one of the example but its not working .Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function click_handler1() { alert("click_handler1"); }
function click_handler2() { alert("click_handler2"); }

    document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", click_handler1, false);
    document.getElementById("id2").addEventListener("click", click_handler2, false);

//window.addEventListener("load", setup, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="id1">some stuff</a>
<a id="id2">stuff</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Put the EventListeners in a window.onload function

Answer (score 30):

Your elements are not found because you're executing the javascript before you've added the elements.
Try moving the script to the bottom of the body:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a id="id1">some stuff</a>
<a id="id2">stuff</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function click_handler1() { alert("click_handler1"); }
function click_handler2() { alert("click_handler2"); }

    document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", click_handler1, false);
    document.getElementById("id2").addEventListener("click", click_handler2, false);

//window.addEventListener("load", setup, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or put code inside `window.onload` event, or use `defer`

Answer (score 12):

Move this to the end of the document, or wrap it with an onload function:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", click_handler1, false);
    document.getElementById("id2").addEventListener("click", click_handler2, false);
});
```

Your code doesn't work because the DOM is not ready yet and you are already trying to fetch id1 and id2.

Answer (score 2):

Your code throws below error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null 
which specifies you need to first define your html element (anchor in this case) and then call methods on it.

What you are doing is - first calling method (addEventListener in this case) and defining the html element (anchor in this case) later on.

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <a id="id1">some crap</a><br>
    <a id="id2">crap</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function click_handler1() { alert("click_handler1"); }
     function click_handler2() { alert("click_handler2"); }

     document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", click_handler1);
     document.getElementById("id2").addEventListener("click", click_handler2);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```