# Why is the addEventListener not triggering the method on click?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I am creating a simple To-Do list. The addEventListener() is supposed to trigger the method `addToDo` and create a new div inside which the lists are appended.

But the method is not triggered and the div isn't added. Tried the solutions from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262693/addeventlistener-not-working-in-javascript) and other questions but they don't seem to fix the problem.

```js
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');

//EventListeners
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addToDo, false);


//Functions
function addToDo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //ToDo Div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todo');

    //Create <li>
    const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
    newToDo.innerText = 'hey';
    newToDo.classList.add('todo-item');
    todoDiv.appendChild(newToDo);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you never append the newly created todo to the `todoList` in the code that you have included.

Comment: Also, `li` is a fit for `ul`, not for `div`.

Answer (score 0):

It is triggered. You just can't see anything changing because newly created `todoDiv` is not being mounted anywhere.

Instead of appending to `todoDiv` try appending to `todoList`.

```js
function addToDo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Create <li>
    const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
    newToDo.innerText = 'hey';
    newToDo.classList.add('todo-item');
    todoList.appendChild(newToDo);
}
```