# addEventListener not working on specific item

Tags: javascript, class, alert, addeventlistener

I have a few instances of addEventListner in my code, and they seem to work alright, but when I use it on this specific portion it does nothing. I'm trying to test it with a simple alert so that when you click the text box on first name, an alert pops up at the top, but right now I'm getting nothing. Here is my  for the name box and my addEventListener call:

```
  <div class="_form_element _x77561130 _full_width " >
    <div class="_field-wrapper form__input-wrapper form__input-wrapper--labelled">
      <input class="form__field form__field--large form__field--text" type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="" />
      <label class="_form-label form__floating-label">
        First Name
      </label>
    </div>      
  </div>
```

and this is my call:

```
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello World!");  
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Tested your code and it works. So we need to know what is different about this code from what you actually have.

Comment: Do you have another element with the same ID earlier in the document? ids should be unique and getElementById will only return the first element that matches.

Comment: *"but right now I'm getting nothing*" - try to log the element before adding the listener `console.log(document.getElementById("fname"))` - what does this give?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of detail to go on here - but an easy thing to forget is to wrap your JS in a function that checks if either the window or document has loaded so that it doesn't fire before the elements exist. It would be helpful to provide any console errors.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
 /* add your code here */
}
```

[Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262693/addeventlistener-not-working-in-javascript/21262734).

Comment: Good thought, but I don't think that's the issue, because OP says "I have a few instances of addEventListner in my code, and they seem to work"

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in the snippet below, so maybe the error is somewhere else.

```js
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello World!");  
});
```

```html
<div class="_form_element _x77561130 _full_width " >
    <div class="_field-wrapper form__input-wrapper form__input-wrapper--labelled">
      <input class="form__field form__field--large form__field--text" type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="" />
      <label class="_form-label form__floating-label">
        First Name
      </label>
    </div>      
  </div>
```

Comment: oddly enough i deleted the code snippet for the addEventListener, and put it back in later and it worked...no idea why but i'm assuming it was something just bugging out in the back end